# SO Documentation for Magento is in Beta

Tags: discussion

I´m not sure if this is the right place to communicate it but the SO Documentation is in beta now with its own part for Magento.
I think 7ochem also made a proposal for this if i remember right

[Stack Overflow Magento Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento/topics)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for flagging it as duplicate, but then I can draw the attention to the original question here on meta ;)

Comment: No worries, I was just about to comment on yours as well. I wasn´t sure if i should post it seperately or not. My main point was to mention it :)